# Xcode compiles and runs an older version of app

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app that's been around for five years and undergone many updates. When I want to start the workflow for an update, I copy all the app files to a new directory, open the new version in Xcode, update version numbers for the different targets, and start to work on the new version. The first step has always been to compile and run the new version to see that I'm starting from a working version. This has always worked, through many updates.

Today I did this, updating my app from 4.1.43 to 4.1.44. I copied all files to a new directory, updated all versions and ran the app. But instead of running version 4.1.44 on the simulator and devices, it runs 4.1.43.

The first build gives me many errors of duplicate interface and file definitions. A clean fixes that, but Xcode still runs 4.1.43, even though I am in the 4.1.44 directory, using only files there. If I go back to 4.1.43, I get the duplicate errors; again, a clean removes them.

Xcode must have some setting that is causing it to use old code and app settings, but I have no idea why or what. I will very much appreciate any insights into what's wrong here and how to correct it.

John

Comment: Did you try to delete Derived Data?

Comment: Yes. Deleted all Derived Data.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this, but still don't know what happened to cause the problem.

After deleting Derived Data and running the app again, I realized that there was no new entry in Derived Data. I checked Preferences/Locations/Derived Data and found that Legacy was selected. Selecting Unique fixed the problem.

Why Legacy was selected is a mystery; I didn't change it and it wasn't that way in the last update. And since Legacy puts the app into a directory unique to the app, it seems it should have run correctly using a Legacy location.

Regardless, that seems to be the answer - make sure Unique is selected for Derived Data.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.
Did an Xcode -> Product -> Clean Build folder. Didn't help.
Closed Xcode, deleted DerivedData, didn't help as well.
A restart solved the problem.